# What is the effect of extending the length of varchar of one field from the MyISAM table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, varchar

I want to extend the length of my one column from my MyISAM table that currently have a billion of records with data type varchar from 30 to 50 because I found out that there is some data that was truncated during uploading because the string is more than 30.

My question is, if I updated the length of this column, is it going to alter all records from my table? If yes, how long it will takes if I have a billion of records on my database?

Comment: How could it not affect all rows? If you widen a column, every row gets a wider column. It will take however long it takes, depending on your individual hardware and database. (You could answer the first question yourself by creating a small sample database and then widening one column and see if all rows get affected, couldn't you?)

Comment: Just want to clarify because I read some question that was similar to mine but I got different answers. By the way thanks for the comment.

Comment: It might take long if the column is indexed.

Answer (score 0):

How long it will take depends on your server config as well as your MySQL config. However, a billion records is not way too large. Since this is varchar type, it will not take a lot of extra spaces for rows where you do not use those extra 20 characters you get. Unlike other data types, Varchar does not occupy space based on your table configuration, but based on the actual length of data you store in it.